# Website for testing POST to .PHP

Tags: php

I have an iOS app, and from that would like to POST to a .php web service.

Currently I am using this site to test (and everything works) http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/cgi-bin/mycgi.pl.

My question is:  are there any sites like the one I posted, that are written in .php so that I can test my app with them ?

Comment: A POST's validity should be independent of implementation (aka, if it works in one, should work in all)

Comment: Don't worry about what language the script that handles your `POST` is written in. `POST` data is `POST` data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like they say, POST is a POST, but... delivering...

```
<?php

$post = print_r($_POST, TRUE);

echo '<pre>', $post, '</pre>';
```

Enjoy.

```
http://instagraph.me/post
```

Example:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 12345
)
```

Edit to "doesn't work" comment:

```
curl -A "Mozilla" -d a=12345 http://instagraph.me/post
Array
(
    [a] => 12345
)
```

What I would suggest you is that you "fake" user agent, just by adding Mozilla you will save yourself possible troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the link this is what I was looking for.  Unfortunately my app doesn't seem to be working with it though :(

Comment: @BloonsTowerDefence please see edit, try to add user agent to your request. (I have no idea how to do that in whatever you use)